# Removing file extension in url not working

Tags: php, .htaccess

**Hi,**

First of all, I'm quite new to `.htaccess` but I have used it a couple of times already in the past.

I have been trying to remove the extensions from my documents in the URL link but it will not work for me. I have browsed numberous stackoverflow questions & answers but none did the trick for me.
I get a 404 error showing that the URL cannot be found.

Example:

https://vps.leonisgeweldig.be/dashboard     --> Not working

https://vps.leonisgeweldig.be/dashboard.php --> Working

Currently, I have a `.htaccess` file in my webservers root dir that follows the rules:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: it's working for me (on localhost)